# Qual container do scene builder posso usar para fazer com que a minha aplicação desktop seja responsiva?

Tags: java, javafx

Estou começando a estudar JavaFX e estou com uma dúvida.

> Qual container do scene builder posso usar para fazer com que a minha aplicação desktop
>   seja responsiva?

O único container que chegou perto do que eu queria, foi o BorderPane, porém, ele é restrito e eu gostaria de mexer na tela livremente, como no AnchorPane.

1 Figura: BorderPane (Responsivo mas não consigo inserir um pane entre o de baixo e o de cima) Minha ideia seria inserir um entre o vermelho e o roxo como mostra na outra figura.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2 Figura: AnchorPane (Não responsivo, mas consigo inserir um pane entre dois HBox.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

**1° Passo: Criar o design no Scene Builder**

Para deixar a aplicação responsiva, criei um AnchorPane, dentro desse AnchorPane eu inseri um Pane e coloquei como `id="PaneTopoTela"`. Esse Pane (elemento filho) é que eu vou poder tornar responsivo a partir do arquivo FXML.

**2° Passo: Inserir código no arquivo FXML:**

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="613.0" prefWidth="748.0" stylesheets="@estilo.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplicationteste.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <Pane id="PaneTopoTela" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"    layoutY="-9.0" prefHeight="92.0" prefWidth="748.0" stylesheets="@estilo.css" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Explicação:**

Percebe que depois do id="PaneTopoTela" eu coloquei AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"?

**Esse AnchorPane.right e left vai ter a mesma funcionalidade no JavaFX que a âncora tem no netbeans. Vai ancorar os elementos na onde você quiser.**

Sobre a âncora no layout do netbeans: Sabe quando você clica com o botão direito em um elemento filho no netbeans e aparece para você "Ancorar -> Esquerda/Direita/Superior/Inferior"? Então, é isso!

**Então no JavaFX, você tem 4 opções, são elas:**

```
AnchorPane.topAnchor

AnchorPane.bottomAnchor

AnchorPane.leftAnchor

AnchorPane.rightAnchor
```

**Se você igualar a 0.0, como eu fiz... Ele vai alinhar o elemento filho dentro do AnchorPane.**

[Para mais informações](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223812/javafx-panel-inside-panel-auto-resizing).

[AnchorPane JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html)